# How can I protect my WebAPI from abuse and avoid sharing API keys?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, identityserver3, azure-api-management

I have a Web API written in C# and hosted in Azure with Azure API Management (AAM) sitting in front of that API and throttling requests.

The clients that call the API will be javascript based and will be calling on behalf of anonymous end users. For example, the home page of a web site might call our API via javascript to present information to an end user without asking them to login.

AAM ensures that callers to the API have a valid API key. There is the potential for this key to be copied and abused though if someone grabs it from the publicly visible source.

**Is it possible to use OAuth2 to obtain a JWT Access Token without human intervention and for this to be exposed on the client?**

OAuth2 can issue expiring JSON Web Tokens which would lower the risk of token theft, but I'm struggling to get this going without any human intervention.

OAuth2 is mostly about end user initiated authorisation but IdentityServer3 seems to have a Hybrid approach. Could I use this Hybrid approach to get the remote web server to request a token by sending the API key from server to server first and then outputting the JWT in the web page for use by the client side script?

This would then hide the API key and only show a JWT that is of use for a few minutes.

AAM can integrate with OAuth2 and inspects JWT Access Tokens, but I don't think it understands this Hybrid flow (it may not need to as we won't be asking for user logins).

Or should I just give up and rate limit requests only?

Comment: Because the API is used for anonymous users on a homepage, is an API key even needed? I.e it is just a public API, albeit you have the ability to rate limit through AAM. For secret API's use OAuth2.

Comment: @MarvinRounce The API key is needed to do the default rate limiting.  There may be multiple users of the API and the subscription key is used to track usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can generate these hybrid JWT keys without user intervention then API Management can validate them and use one of the claims as a key for doing rate limiting.  Normally rate limiting is done based on API Management subscription keys, but the new [advanced rate limiting policies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn894078.aspx#LimitCallRateByKey) allow you rate limit based on any expression.

I'm not familiar with how the IdentityServer hybrid mode keys work, but usually if there is non-interactive login, then there is some kind of secret that needs to be protected.  This is always a challenge when running code on the client.

The API Management HTTP API does have a method to regenerate keys.  You could use this to implement your own token expiry mechanism to limit the impact of key theft.